# Confluence Macro: How to include content

Tags: confluence

There are these two macros available in Confluence: [Excerpt Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/excerpt-macro-658736866.html) and [Excerpt Include Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/excerpt-include-macro-658736865.html), but these are somewhat limited.

I created my own User Macro to extend the existing [Excerpt Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/excerpt-macro-658736866.html) in a way that I can add some parameters to the excerpt, like ID, etc.

I am also able to get the content from my macro via the REST api in my code, which is cool.

BUT, I am unable to find a way to get the content and include it into another page via another macro.

**In other words, I am trying to figure out a way to create my own User Macro to extend the existing [Excerpt Include Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/excerpt-include-macro-658736865.html).**

Is there a way to see the Template content for these existing Confluence Macros, or is there a way to have a User Macro include some content from some other page?

Answer (score 0):

This is not your exact answer, but there is a plug-in multiexcerpt which probably does exactly what you are looking for.